# Multiple CSS link with title

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building two jQuery based plugin, and I'd like to include the necessary css files in the html document.

First, when I included the js and css, it worked perfectly, like this:

```
<script src="/apps/calendar/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/calendar/css/style.css" title="calendar-style">
```

Then I added the second js and css. It is necessary to give the css file a title, because there are cases when I want to insert css rule from the js to its css. So when I give title to the second css, so the header has the following lines, it doesn't work. I can open it from the browsers inspector, so its loaded, however its rules have no effect.

```
<script src="/apps/calendar/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/calendar/css/style.css" title="calendar-style">    
<script src="/apps/filter/js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/apps/filter/css/style.css" title="filter-style">
```

When I remove title attribute from the second css, it works. What can be the problem? Maybe only one css can have a title attribute, or something else?

Comment: It's not the lines or link tags, please show the relevant JS where you're selecting a stylesheet to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"…it defines a preferred or an alternate stylesheet. Incorrectly using it may cause the stylesheet to be ignored." See [Correctly Using Titles With External Stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web_Standards/Correctly_Using_Titles_With_External_Stylesheets).

> According to the HTML 4.01 specification, only one of the preferred stylesheets can be used at a time. Therefore, given the above example, only one of the two preferred stylesheets will be applied to the document. The specification does not supply a procedure to decide which one should be used, so user agents are free to make whatever choice they like.

> Therefore, any link to a stylesheet that includes a title attribute cannot be persistent, and is likely to be ignored by the Web browser. Any link element referring to a stylesheet with a title attribute must be either preferred or alternate, depending on the value of the rel attribute.

Perhaps an id makes more sense for your purposes?

Comment: On that same time the linked article was written, `id` attribute in `link` element wasn't valid. I'm not sure if any of these stand today, as the information is almost 20 years old.

Comment: Thank you thats the answer! However a cannot add rule to a css based on its id, but I am solving the problem by appending a custom <style></style> tag to the file header by the js file.

Comment: Thanks, @Teemu. This isn't something I've thought much about—not at all recently–so my id suggestion may be invalid. Off the top of my head it seemed like an obvious choice for distinguishing stylesheets.